# Error BlockingMessageSender of message processor in WSO2

Tags: proxy, wso2

I'm trying to use the message forwarding processor in WSO2 (4.8.1).

The context is the follow:

1) I've my messages in a Message Store
2) I use my  message forwarding processor to extract messages from the store and invoke a wso2 proxy
3) my proxy invoke an external service

I'm testing the SOAP Fault of my external service.

Here you are my code

My message forwarding processor configuration is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><messageProcessor xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" name="AnotherCapForwardMessageProcessor" targetEndpoint="AnotherCapProxyEndPoint" messageStore="OperCupIDStore">
 <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">AnotherCapProcessorReply</parameter>
<parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">2</parameter>
<parameter name="client.retry.interval">5000</parameter>
<parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
<parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">AnotherCapProcessorFault</parameter>
<parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
```

and my proxy is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AnotherCapProxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - BEGINNING OF IN SEQUENCE .... "/>
        </log>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="what" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - MESSAGE FROM OPERCUPIDSTORE...."/>
        </log>
        <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="false" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="false" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="InternalCodErr" value="WSO2_xxx" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" name="ProcessingID" expression="//p:id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="what" expression="fn:concat('****[ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - PROCESSING ID: ',get-property('default','ProcessingID'))"/>
        </log>
        <xslt xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" key="gov:xslt/getInputCUPXml_Transform.xslt" source="$body">
            <property name="idOp" expression="get-property('default','ProcessingID')"/>
        </xslt>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="what" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - CALLING GAMOPERA FOR THE XML REQUEST TO INVOKE SIMON.... "/>
        </log>
        <header name="Action" scope="default" value=" "/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="AnotherCapGamoperaCreateXMLServiceEndpoint"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - BEGINNING OF OUT SEQUENCE .... "/>
            <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - THE GAMOPERA RESPONSE ...."/>
        </log>
        <filter xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/s11:Fault | s12:Body/s12:Fault">
            <then>
                <property name="ErrorCode" value="WSO2_004" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - SOAP FAULT !!! SOMETHING WENT WRONG CALLING GAMOPERA IN GETTING XML ...."/>
                    <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('operation','ErrorCode')"/>
                </log>
            </then>
            <else>
                <property name="ErrorCode" value="WSO2_003" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - NOT COMPLETE RESPONSE FROM GAMOPERA IN GETTING XML ..."/>
                    <property name="ERROR_CODE = " expression="get-property('default','ErrorCode')"/>
                </log>
            </else>
        </filter>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="where" value="********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - BEGINNING OF FAULT SEQUENCE .... "/>
            <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_DETAIL" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_EXCEPTION" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
        </log>
        <send/>
    </faultSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL key="gov:wsdl/AnotherWSDL.wsdl"/>
```

So my message processor try two times, then deactive itself.

When execute the log is the follow ...

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:17,128]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  where = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - BEGINNING OF IN SEQUENCE ....  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:17,128]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /wso003/services/AnotherCapProxy, WSAction: urn:process, SOAPAction: urn:process, MessageID: urn:uuid:2262a521-97da-471a-8691-da9016cbeac3, Direction: request, what = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - MESSAGE FROM OPERCUPIDSTORE...., Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
  <gam:process xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->         
  <gam:id>459</gam:id></gam:process>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:17,129]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  what = ****[ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - PROCESSING ID: 459 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:17,132]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /wso003/services/AnotherCapProxy, WSAction: urn:process, SOAPAction: urn:process, MessageID: urn:uuid:2262a521-97da-471a-8691-da9016cbeac3, Direction: request, what = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - CALLING GAMOPERA FOR THE XML REQUEST TO INVOKE SIMON.... , Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
<p:gestWso2GetInputCUPXml xmlns:p="http://operintegrated.interfacews.operserv.gamopera.csi.it/"><input><idOperazione>459</idOperazione></input></p:gestWso2GetInputCUPXml></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:18,980]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:bf5762a3-2324-4fed-8b56-fdc7cdd4cac2, Direction: response, where = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - BEGINNING OF OUT SEQUENCE .... , where = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - THE GAMOPERA RESPONSE ...., Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Errore imprevisto occorso durante l'esecuzione del metodo:java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring><detail><ns1:Exception xmlns:ns1="http://operintegrated.interfacews.operserv.gamopera.csi.it/"></ns1:Exception></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:18,980]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  where = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROXY] - FAULT !!! SOMETHING WENT WRONG CALLING GAMOPERA IN GETTING XML ...., ERROR_CODE = WSO2_004 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:18,985] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService} -  BlockingMessageSender of message processor [AnotherCapForwardMessageProcessor] failed to send message to the endpoint {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:18,986]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /wso003/services/OperCupPrepareProxy.OperCupPrepareProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:process, SOAPAction: urn:process, MessageID: urn:uuid:4ECFA324C9FBB675AB842060829710186-582880576, Direction: request, where = ********** [ANOTHER-CAP-PROCESSOR-FAULT] - BEGINNING PROCESSOR FAULT SEQUENCE .... , Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Errore imprevisto occorso durante l'esecuzione del metodo:java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring><detail><ns1:Exception xmlns:ns1="http://operintegrated.interfacews.operserv.gamopera.csi.it/"></ns1:Exception></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 11:00:18,992]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor} -  Successfully deactivated the message processor [AnotherCapForwardMessageProcessor] {org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor}
```

I see that the execution doesn't cross in the message processor retry sequence and probably something goes wrong when i close the proxy out sequence.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Bye

Cesare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send back the soap fault to the message processor in your proxy outSequence, the message processor execute it's fault sequence : HTTP Status code of your message must have a value different from '500'. You should log it (use property $axis2:HTTP_SC)

When the fault sequence is executed 'max.delivery.attempts' times, the message processor is deactivated, if you want it to redeliver the message indefinitely, set this value to -1